# Why application can be marked as "not responding" even if it pump messages?

Tags: c++, winapi

Why application can be marked as "not responding" even if it pump messages?

Message loop looks like this:

```
bool bLoop = true;
while (bLoop)
{
    int iMsgCount = 0;

    MSG msg;
    while ( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE) )
    {
        iMsgCount++;

        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            bLoop = false;
            break;
        {

        AppPreprocessIME(msg);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Log( "Message loop (messages) %d ", iMsgCount );
    Log( "ThreadId %d", GetCurrentThreadId() );

    if(!bLoop)
       break;


    // Update/DirectX draw/etc.
}
```

Loop goes fine (it writes log messages), but Windows still marks it as "not responding".

Is there any other check windows do to make such decision? Or something else can lead to this behavior?

Also, window become responsive if debugger attached (started from debugger or attached during "not responding" state). I guess that debugger hooks something or alter message queue processing.

Comment: are you able to generate dump file (in unresponsive state) and analyze using windbg?

Comment: I have no idea what to analyze. Application is still running, it writes log, peeks messages etc.

Comment: Um, if `PeekMessage` returns 0, then that exits your loop and you stop pumping messages.

Comment: No, it doesn't. There are big loop around this code.

Comment: Please read the guidelines of Stack Overflow, you are supposed to extract a minimal example and that is for good reasons.

Comment: This is valid example. Look:
1. PeekMessage returns 0
2. Log show that (so we DO peek messages, just there are no any)
3. BUT window appears as "not responding"

Question - "Why?". What else can affect it?
May be something blocks messages?

Comment: The inner `while` loop is setting the stage for a subtle bug: If `PeekMessage` retrieves a `WM_QUIT` message, while there are other messages in the message queue, the outer `while` loop never gets a chance to see it. When the application receives a request to terminate, it tears down its UI, and keeps spinning indefinitely. It missed its only chance to terminate. The inner `while` should really be an `if`.

Comment: IInspectable:

Oh, it is a bug, but I don't think it cause this - if so why it works normally with debugger attached?

Comment: IInspectable: I fixed this bug, but application still hanging, so it wasn't a cause.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: What does the application do when it has nothing to do? We can't tell from the code given.

Comment: Attaching a debugger changes the behavior. This is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx): *"If a top-level window stops responding to messages for more than several seconds, the system considers the window to be not responding and replaces it with a ghost window [...]. When an application is being debugged, the system does not generate a ghost window."*

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]

Comment: There is another bug in the outer loop.  When `PeekMessage()` returns 0, no message data has been copied to `msg`. But the outer loop assumes `msg` always contains a valid message, and that is not the case in this code. If `msg` contains random garbage and its `message` field *happens* to contain a value equal to `WM_QUIT` the outer loop will exit even though no `WM_QUIT` message was actually received. Use a separate BOOL variable to break the outer loop, and set that variable only when `WM_QUIT` is received.

Comment: IInspectable: Oh, that's explain some part. I didn't noticed that remark before, thanks!

Comment: David Heffernan: I'm trying to do so, but since I have no idea what can cause it I can't make short example to that reproduce it. I think if I'll find one I'll see solution immediately.

Comment: Remy Lebeau: Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: Does this happen every time you run your application, or only occasionally?

Comment: Harry Johnston: Every time application became background. Also, one thing puzzles me - I can attach debugger to not responding application and it became responsive. Peeks messages, reacts to input, works just fine.